# Common Context Menu at application level

Tags: c#, custom-contextmenu

I have a very huge business application that contains almost all types of controls + third party controls. Now I have a requirement where I have to open a Form on **"ctrl + double click"** on any control(grid, cell, row, treenode, button, etc.. etc..)..

Is it possible in Winforms C#.Net.

I tried with this code as well but it didn't help

```
const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;//client area
const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;//non-client area
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
    return;
  if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    return;
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I am not sure if I can create a **Common Context Menu at application level**
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use keyboard and mouse hooks for that.

Here are some great articles that will get you started.

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-)

And

[WPF, low-level keyboard hook sample](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8)